# How to create numpy arrays from list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning numerical computing in python and tried the following code to integrate a function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

def integration(z):
    if np.isscalar(z):
        y, err = spi.quad(lambda x: 1/np.sqrt(1+x),0,z)
        " spi.quad returns integrated value with error"
        print y   # result for scalar input

    else:
        for x in z:
            y, err = spi.quad(lambda x: 1/np.sqrt(1+x),0,x)
            print y # result for arrays
    return
```

But the result I get is not an array I need an array for further computation. I get the following result:

```
z = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> integration(z)
0.0
0.108185106779
0.21108319357
0.309401076759
0.403700850309
......
```

Any help here ***how should I modify my code to get numpy array***

Comment: I don't understand -- do you want to print something, or return something to whoever calls `integration`?

Comment: Remove print y. return y.  And then mat=integration(z); print mat

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

def integration(z):
    if np.isscalar(z): z = np.asarray([z])
    y = np.empty_like(z)
    for i in range(z.shape[0]):
        y[i], err = spi.quad(lambda x: 1/np.sqrt(1+x),0,z[i])
    return y
```

Test:

```
>>> z = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> intg_z = integration(z)
>>> print intg_z
[ 0.          0.10818511  0.21108319  0.30940108  0.40370085  0.49443826
  0.5819889   0.66666667  0.74873708  0.82842712]
```

Comment: Everything after the `:` on line 5 needs to be indented and on line 6.

Comment: This copy/pasted, runs fine on my IPython notebook